# Some elements are not being selected using C#/Selenium

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, selenium

Okay this is strange. When I am at work and run my tests, some elements do not get recognized, therefore, the tests do not run properly.  But when I remote into my machine from home, the same machine that I use at work, the automated tests run just fine.  I'm using VS2010.

For instance I have a simple statement to add the date to a field:

```
FieldValue = DateTime.Today.AddDays(5).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

So when the automated test is running when I remote into the machine, it works fine. When I'm here at work it does not input the value.  But what is even stranger is when I stop the program from running, all of a sudden the date appears in the field.

I don't know if it is some restrictions here at work that is for some reason or another not allowing the date to be inputted?  I just don't know....

Comment: This needs much much much more information. What version of Selenium? What browser and version of that browser? Can you reproduce this on another public site? Is this an ajax'ified site? Have you used explicit waits? Show us a small reproducible scenario. Does it makes any difference what browser/driver you use?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here from the limited info you provided, this sounds like a timing issue. Try introducing an explicit wait for each element before referencing it. The fact that it works when you are not at work suggests that the slower connection may have sufficient delay to allow the elements to load (This may not be a valid assumption depending on your setup).

Comment: Hi - so I tried it with Chrome & IE and it worked just fine. I am using Sel 2.0.  FF = 21.0 is what browser/version I was using.  I am fairly new to the Selenium game so I am learning quickly and I have seen some documentation on implicit and explicit waits. I will look into that and implement it in the code - thank you

Comment: I added an explicit wait and it works great now - thank you. But I've ran into another problem.  So I put a collection of id's from the application into an array and looping through each one to set a particular value or click on an element.  Everything seems fine but when I try to click this one radio button on a particular page, for some reason it seems to skip over to the next element and clicks that fine. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: We'd need to see the HTML of that element and what code you are using to select it.